# Solving recurrence relation with two recursive calls

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

I'm studying the worst case runtime of quicksort under the condition that it will never do a *very* unbalanced partition for varying definitions of *very*.

In order to do this I ask myself the question what the runtime $T(n, p)$ would be in the case quicksort always happens to partition in some fraction $0 < p \leq {1\over 2}$ such that $\lfloor{p(n-1)}\rfloor$ elements are in the left partition and $\lceil(1 - p)(n - 1)\rceil$ are in the right partition (leaving $1$ element, the pivot, in the middle).

It shouldn't be hard to see that $T(n, p)$ gives an upper bound for the worst case where $p$ is the maximally unbalanced allowed partition, as any partition with fraction $> p$ will be more balanced and have a smaller runtime, and any fraction $<p$ is not allowed.

It's obvious that $T(n, {1 \over 2})$ is the best case and $T(n, 0)$ is the worst case of quicksort. Both have easy recurrence relations that are found in any educational resource. But I have no clue how to study $T(n, p)$ in general. The obvious relation would be:

$$T(n, p) = n + T(\lfloor{p(n-1)}\rfloor, p) + T(\lceil(1 - p)(n - 1)\rceil, p)$$

Here I get stuck. I've tried searching around, but all literature that I could understand about divide and conquer algorithms took the "divide" literally and *"cheated"* the analysis using the fact that the partitions are always equal in size, merging the terms into one times a constant.

I do not know how to deal with two recursive calls, and I do not know if it is safe to remove the rounding. Is this possible to solve analytically, and if yes, how?

P.S.: I'm not interested in asymptotics (which is easy to show $\Theta(n \log n)$ for any constant $p$). I am interested in how much slower quicksort becomes as $p$ gets smaller, for example I'm interested in the ratio $T(n, 0.25) \over T(n, 0.5)$.

P.P.S: As an undergraduate student I apologize if I've made obvious things too lengthy or underexplained nontrivialities. And while I don't know if it's looked down upon here so much as other SE sites, I'll note that this is personal interest, not homework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mention, the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) shows that the solution to the recurrence $T(n,p)$ is $O(n\log n)$ for all $p \in (0,1)$. However, this does not reveal the nature of the dependence on $p$. To determine the latter, we can use a recursion tree approach.

At the root of the recursion tree is the interval $\{1,\ldots n\}$. Its two children are the intervals $\{1,\ldots,pn\}$ and $\{pn+1,\ldots,n\}$, whose total length is again $n$. Each of these nodes has two children (assuming $n$ is large enough), and so on. For simplicity we ignore rounding errors, that is, we assume that $pn$ is an integer; this is just a technicality, and I wouldn't worry about it. We stop the process whenever a node has length at most $1$. The complexity of the algorithm is proportional to the total length of intervals in the tree. When $p \neq 1/2$, the *leaves* (nodes at which we stop the process) have different depth, and that makes it more difficult to determine the overall complexity.

We can obtain a simple upper bound by noting that the tree has at most $\log_{1-p} (1/n)$ levels: each node is at least a factor of $1-p$ smaller than its parent. Just like in the analysis for $p = 1/2$, the total length of intervals at any level is at most $n$, and we obtain an upper bound of $O(n\log_{1-p} (1/n))$ on the running time. Since $\log_{1-p} (1/n) = \log n/\log (1-p)^{-1}$ and $\log (1-p)^{-1} = -\log (1-p) = p \pm O(p^2)$ for small $p$, we can write this as $O(n\log n/p)$.

Here is a more accurate calculation. Consider level $t$. Suppose we don't stop the process upon reaching a small interval. We can generate a random vertex by taking $t$ steps, in each of which we go left (say) with probability $p$ and right (say) with probability $1-p$. Each time we take a left step the log of the length of the interval decreases by $-\log p$, and each time we take a right step it decreases by $-\log (1-p)$. A vertex is in the actual tree of the log of the length decreased by at most $\log n$. The total weight of intervals on level $t$ of the tree is exactly the probability that a vertex generated according to this process correspond to a decrease of at most $\log n$. That is, if $D$ is the distribution which is equal to $-\log p$ with probability $p$ and to $-\log(1-p)$ with probability $1-p$, and $X_1,\ldots,X_t \sim D$ are independent, then the total weight of level $t$ is $\Pr[X_1+\cdots+X_t \leq \log n]$. For super-constant $t$, the random variable $X_1+\cdots+X_t$ is roughly normally distributed with mean $[-p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)]t$ and variance linear in $t$, so for $t$ satisfying $[-p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)]t \leq (\log n)/2$, say, the probability will be very close to $1$, while for $t$ satisfying $[-p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)]t \geq 2\log n$, say, it will be very close to zero. Defining $h(p) = -p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)$ (known as the binary entropy function), we conclude that the running time is $\Theta(n\log n/h(p))$ (uniform in $p$, as $n\to\infty$). As $p\to 0$ we have $h(p) \approx -p\log p$, and so our earlier estimate was not tight.

Another way of looking at the same analysis is by having an infinite sequence of independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ as before, and defining a stopping time $T$ to be the first time $t$ such that $X_1 + \cdots + X_t \geq \log n$. The running time is then proportional to $n\mathbb{E}[T]$. [The elementary renewal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#Properties_of_renewal_processes_and_renewal-reward_processes) then states that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[T]/\log n = 1/\mathbb{E}[D] = 1/h(p)$, implying that the total size of intervals equals $(1+o(1))n\log n/h(p)$. More accurately, for every constant $p$ the total size of intervals is $(1+\alpha_p(n))n\log n/h(p)$, where $\alpha_p(n) = o(n)$. The convergence in the elementary renewal theorem is exponential in the time parameter — $\log n$ in our case — so should be polynomial in $n$, that is, $\alpha_p(n) = O(n^{-C_p})$. The convergence is also probably uniform for $p \in (\delta,1-\delta)$ for any $\delta > 0$.

---

Summarizing, the total length of intervals in the recursion tree, which is proportional to the running time, is of the following form for every $p$: $$ T(n,p) = (1+o(1)) \frac{n\log n}{h(p)}, $$ where $\log n$ and $h(p) = -p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p)$ are taken to the same base, and the $o(1)$ is a function depending on $p$ and tending to $0$ with $n$.

Moreover, it is probably true that for any $\delta > 0$ and any $p \in (\delta,1-\delta)$ it is true that the total length of intervals is of the form $$T(n,p) = (1+O(n^{-C_\delta})) \frac{n\log n}{h(p)}, $$ where $C_\delta > 0$ and the hidden big O constant depend only on $\delta$. In particular, it should be the case that for all constant $p_1,p_2$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{T(n,p_1)}{T(n,p_2)} = \frac{h(p_2)}{h(p_1)}, $$
and the convergence is polynomially fast.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Yuval. I'm a bit confused by the fact that you used $\Theta$ in your summary. $h(p)$ is a constant, and doesn't that mean that it's irrelevant under $\Theta$? I decided to write [a little test program](https://gist.github.com/orlp/3ddc35db57f6bdb2bad3), which showed that for $n = 100000000000000$ comparing $T(n, 0.1) / T(n, 0.5)$ between the analytical method and a computational one gave an error of 0.03. That seems rather large, or is this to be expected?

Comment: The constant in the $\Theta$ is uniform in $p$. More accurately, for some constants $c, C$ it is the case that for each $p$ there exists $N_p$ such that for $n\geq N_p$, $cn\log n/h(p) \leq T(n, p) \leq Cn\log n/h(p) $. You can probably get an even stronger statement of the form $T(n, p)=(1+o(1))Cn\log n/h(p) $ for each fixed $p$, where the little o is with respect to $n$ (but could depend on $p$); $C$ should *not* depend on $p$.

Comment: Convergence to the limit depends on $\log n$, so you might need $\log n$ to be large in order to get a really good approximation. On the other hand, a relative error of 0.03 doesn't sound so large. You can try to fix $n$ and plot the running time as a function of $p$, comparing it to $1/h(p) $.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't mean a relative error of 0.03, but an absolute one (2.13222 vs 2.10339). Plotting $T(n, p)$ as a function of $p$, relative to $1 / h(p)$ gave a relative difference of 4%, with $T(10^{11}, 0.05) * h(0.05)$ being 96% of $T(10^{11}, 0.4) * h(0.4)$.

Comment: I added a more refined analysis that also predicts the constant $C$ (it should equal 1). The ratio between your simulation and $n\log n/h(p)$ should tend to 1, though not necessarily very quickly.

Comment: You can find a completely formal analysis here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6602.pdf, which also references two prior proofs of the same formula. The main complication might be dealing with the rounding (the fact that $pn$ is not always an integer), though there might be a cheap way of getting rid of this: approximate $p$ by a rational number $a/b$ and look only at $n = b^k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuval, an amazing effort (+1 and accepted). I will look at the paper and attempt to understand it all (bear in mind I'm still an undergraduate). I do have one question about your answer where google didn't seem to help - you used the term "super-constant". What does this mean?

Comment: Super-constant is a function tending to infinity with respect to the relevant variable (in this case $n$). It is the same as $\omega(1)$.